# oracle installation in centos6

Tags: oracle, installation, centos

I am using centos6 on server machine.

Now I have to install the oracle11g database on that system.

I read the oracle documentation for the installation process, but its first instruction is to install `XTERM`. I have confusions about XTERM and I'm not able download it either.

Then I was tried this [blog post](http://eduardo-lago.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-install-oracle-11g-database.html), but it has not helped me to with the oracle installation.

I can't install oracle11g with a GUI. How can I install this using only the command-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try silent installation.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e22489/app_nonint.htm

From the documentation:

Use silent mode to do the following installations:

- Complete an unattended installation, which you schedule using
  operating system utilities such as at.
- Complete several similar installations on multiple systems without user interaction.
- **Install the software on a system that does not have X Window System software
  installed on it.**

The installer displays progress information on the terminal that you used to start it, but it does not display any of the installer screens.

Comment: I want to know about what is the purpose of XTERM. can I install oracle 11g without XTERM ?

Comment: Xterm is the terminal emulator for X Windows. Off late I have not done DB installations without X Windows.